# background worker.exe process in task manager

Tags: security, malware, malware-detection

Today i noticed background worker.exe process in task manager. When I try to kill the process, it says: You don't have permission to do that (like a respectable trojan). Malware bytes does not recognize it. How can i get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

This is virus.

I got this one today too. It is located in C:\ProgramData\Digger and I used VirusTotal to scan it and it says it is BitCoinMiner-B.

For now, I don't know is it safe to delete, but you should scan your computer for viruses ASAP.

I will update this answer as I found more about it

Edit1 : I was able to stop it without any problem

Comment: Yup, used bitdefender to remove it. After the antivirus deleted the files i was able to kill the porcess.

Answer (score 0):

Used RKill to quickly kill the process, then deleted the directory at C:\ProgramData\Digger - Quick and easy! :D